# reverse tethering : ping failed from device to PC

Tags: android, tethering

I am trying to reverse tether my rooted samsung s duos via usb. First of all i enabled the usb tethering option in the phone, then provided static ip of 192.168.42.128 for new connection on windows PC and set static ip of 192.168.42.129 for my device, 192.168.42.128 as the added default gateway. Now i can ping my phone from the PC, but when i try to ping my PC from my phone, ping does not work.

Can you please point out the problem. Thanks in advance.